# How do I use the output from one DataFlow task as an Input in another DataFlow Task?

Tags: ssis

I have `Data Flow Task A` which merges a bunch of tables together.

I want to use the output from `Data Flow Task A` in `Data Flow Task B` to continue merging tables.

How do I do this?

The reason the tasks in `Data Flow Task A` are not in `Data Flow Task B`, is because `Data Flow Task A` is also going to provide data for `Data Flow Task C`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. At least, not directly.

At our disposal we have 3 output classifications: table, file and a local in-memory recordset object.

Since you want to use the rows as a source, we can already throw out the recordset because while we have a "Recordset Destination", lamentably we have no "Recordset Source"

That leaves us with tables versus files. This is dealer's choice. I favor tables because that's usually easier if I have to debug something but writing to a file works just fine. If you *do* write to a file, the Raw file option will provide better performance over a flat file as it will be in a binary format which eliminates the processing overhead of parsing and interpreting the data against locale rules.

I guess a final option could be to add a MultiCast into your data flow A and shoehorn the logic for B and C into it. The challenge with this approach is that it quickly becomes painful to edit the data flow due to dependencies between componentns

Comment: I feel like that's an oversight by the SSIS team. I'll give the file option a go.